# Count(Distinct x) and Group By y

Tags: sql, database, count, distinct, logparser

I have entries with date and time. I want the results to be grouped by the hour (00, 01, 02) and that works, but when i want to get the distinct counts of users, there is an error.

```
Select Substr(time, 0, 2) as Hour,
 Count(date) as Hits,
 Count(Distinct ip) as Users,
 Count(Distinct X-Forwarded-For) as ForwardedUsers
From table 
Group By Hour
```

EDIT:
I am using the LogParser from Microsoft and i am able to use `Group By Hour` as it is and `X-Forwarded-For` is also no problem.
The question is how i can use `Count(Distinct ip)` within the group by

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And what is `Count(Distinct X-Forwarded-For)`?  It is unusual to use `count(distinct)` with a numerical expression.

Comment: Try putting `X-Forwarded-For` in backticks since it contains special characters.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Many dbms specific tips here...'

Comment: `X-Forwarded-For` is an invalid identifier in (standard) SQL. Which DBMS are you using

Comment: I am using LogParser from Microsoft to parse IIS Advanced Logs via tvs

Comment: So you are using SQL Server?

Comment: so you want distinct values with non distinct values? count multiple dates but distinct users? same user could use it twice. Either get the distinct for all or split it up into many CTE's and join them together

Comment: "but when i want to get the distinct counts of users, there is an error" - Which??? Maybe something like "unknown column ip"? Does your table actually contain a column called ip?

Comment: And `time` is a string? And why `count(date)` instead of a mere `count(*)`?  Is `date` nullable and you only want to count non-null occurrences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately LogParser does not support `DISTINCT` aggregate functions together with `GROUP BY`. This should have been clear from the error message you get with the query above:

> Error: Semantic Error: aggregate functions with DISTINCT arguments are
>   not supported with GROUP BY clauses

One trick you could do is to remove the `GROUP BY` clause altogether and calculate instead `COUNT DISTINCT(hourlyIp)` where `hourlyIp` is a string built concatenating the hour with the IP address. You'll have then to breakup the `hourlyIp` field back into its components when you process the results.

Answer (score 1):

Most database engines to not allow you to group by alias names.  Change this:

```
Group by Hour
```

to this:

```
Substr(time, 0, 2)
```

Comment: And according to ANSI SQL only columns may be listed in the GROUP BY clause.